# How to find the frequencies, amplitudes, and initial phases of the original signals from a sum of the signals?

Tags: fourier-analysis, wave-equation

I have checked the other related posts (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42670/rebuilding-original-signal-from-frequencies-amplitude-and-phase-obtained-after) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087301/how-does-the-fourier-transform-get-you-the-frequency-amplitude)), but it didn't solve my problem which is explained below:

Consider three simple sine waves as follows:

$$
x_{1}=a_{1} \sin \left (\omega_{1} t+\phi_{1}   \right ) \\
x_{2}=a_{2} \sin \left (\omega_{2} t+\phi_{2}   \right ) \\
x_{3}=a_{3} \sin \left (\omega_{3} t+\phi_{3}   \right ) 
$$
where $x_{i}$ is the instantaneous value of the corresponding signal, $a_{i}, \omega_{i}$ and $\phi_{i}$ are the amplitude, frequency and phase respectively.

If I add these three waves, I will get

$x=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}$

How can I get back the amplitude, frequency and phase values of the component signals from $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Fourier transform of $x(t)$, let us call it $X(\omega)$. Since the Fourier transform is linear and $x(t) = x_1(t)+x_2(t)+x_3(t)$ we have $X(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)+X_3(\omega)$. For $x_i(t) = a_i \sin(\omega_i \cdot t + \phi_i)$ we have $X_i(\omega) = \jmath \pi a_i \left(\delta(\omega+\omega_i)- \delta(\omega-\omega_i)\right)$ where $\delta(\omega)$ is the Dirac delta "function". Therefore, the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ is given by
$$X(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \jmath \pi a_i {\rm e}^{\jmath \phi_i}\left(\delta(\omega+\omega_i)- \delta(\omega-\omega_i)\right).$$
Therefore, if the frequencies are distinct, in theory all you have to do is to find the delta "peaks" in the spectrum. Their location will tell you the frequencies $\omega_i$, their complex amplitude will give $a_i$ (magnitude) and $\phi_i$ (phase).

Of course in practice we are usually faced with the situation that we do not have the entire function $x(t)$ available but only a limited number of **samples** of $x(t)$. In this case, the problem is called harmonic retrieval and has been very well studied in the literature. There are non-parametric ("low resolution") schemes based on the DFT (which can identify frequencies only if they are separated by more than one over the observation window) as well as parametric schemes that achieve a resolution that is only limited by the amount of additive noise (look for things like Capons method, Prony method, the MUSIC algorithm, ESPRIT). Alternatively, you can always use a maximum likelihood estimator. Such methods should be covered in most textbooks on digital signal processing.

If the frequencies are not distinct, the problem does not have a unique solution, see John's answer.

Comment: And the problem becomes much more complicated in real life, when the 3 sine waves are modulated in frequency and amplitude. In that case a dynamic programming algorithm tracking the waves in the spectrum is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no solution to this problem in general. For suppose that all three frequencies are $1$, all three phases are zero, and $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 3$. Then $x(t) = 6\sin(t)$. From this, it's impossible to recover the values of the $a_i$, for $a_1 = 6, a_2 = a_3 = 0$ is an equally good answer.

Second, you're only going to be able to recover the frequencies/amplitudes up to sign, because $A \sin(kt) = (-A) \sin ((-k)t)$, and the phases up to an additive multiple of $2\pi$.

And, of course, the solutions can be permuted: you cannot, even when you've broken the signal into three parts, know which one came from $x_1$, which from $x_2$, and which from $x_3$.

Now let's assume that the frequencies are all different, but unknown. One question is, "Do you need the exact values, or is this a question of deriving answers from physical observed data, where approximate answers would suffice, because the data is also approximate?"

I'm going to assume you need precise answers, and that you have no idea what the frequencies might be. If you *did* have a sense of the greatest frequency, then a fast fourier transform with a peak frequency about 100 times your highest-possible would give you a very good idea of the three true frequencies.

For the last case -- different frequencies, etc.: @Florian seems to have written a very nice summary, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for editing my question. Yes, if the waves have the same frequency and phase, there cannot be any unique solution. However, consider the case where the frequencies and phases are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). Let's use the definition:

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{f(t)\right\}(\xi) \triangleq \widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-2\pi it\xi}dt$$

Then:

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{a\sin(\omega t+\phi)\right\}(\xi) = \frac{a}{2}e^{-2\pi i \phi\xi/\omega}\left[\delta\left(\xi-\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\right)+\delta\left(\xi+\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\right)\right]$$

You can recover the coefficients of the deltas by integrating the Fourier transform of your function in a small interval and taking the limit:

$$L = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} \widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi$$

For $f(t)=a\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, if you do that around $c=\omega/2\pi$, the limit of the integral gives $L = \frac{a}{2}e^{-2\pi i \phi c/\omega} = \frac{a}{2}e^{-\pi i \phi}$. So $a = 2\|L\|$ and $\phi = -\frac{1}{\pi}\angle L$.

[This link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) has some examples of how to do this on Matlab with discrete data and the Fast Fourier Transform.

Comment: in your link there is nothing about retrieving the frequency of several sines plus noise

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, there is: "Define the frequency domain f and plot the single-sided amplitude spectrum P1. The amplitudes are not exactly at 0.7 and 1, as expected, because of the added noise. On average, longer signals produce better frequency approximations."

Comment: I don't think you understand why it is complicated to retrieve the sines in real life.

Comment: @user1952009 Well, I've done it before and got very good results. The only problem is I had to calculate the average of the *power* density (or FFT squared) in a small interval and then take the square root to recover the amplitude for that interval.

Comment: This is not how we do it. The target is to minimize $\sum_n |x_n-\sum_{j=1}^k A_j e^{i \omega_j n}|^2$. A possible way is to find the largest peak giving an approximation of $\omega_1,A_1$, and to improve it with gradient descent, then to substract $A_1 e^{i \omega_1 n}$ and continue with the obtained new largest peak. It works well if the frequencies are spaced enough. Otherwise, use the eigenvalue algorithms (Music and Esprit) mentioned by Florian which gives the same result for well-spaced frequencies, and a better one (a smaller $k$) otherwise.

Comment: @user1952009 That goes to exactly $0$ for the FFT. What you probably mean is to recover the coefficients of the function *before* being corrupted by noise. This is a different problem. It depends on your noise profile and on how you define your error function (usually people use the norm squared, by the way).

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. The windowing introduces some noise. So to be clear, you tried with $k=1$, but you don't see how the problem is more complicated when $k > 1$ ${}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 This works for any finite $k$. The continuous case uses the whole signal, there is no windowing. And the discrete case also gives the exact result, because windowing has no effect on the FFT, as long as the Nyquist criterion is respected. I will abstain from extending this discussion because it's not adding anything relevant to the OP's question or my answer.

Comment: $y_n = \sin(2 \pi n m/N)$  is not the same as $y_n = \sin(2 \pi f n)$. I'm telling you to forget about the ideal case with only one perfect peak, because I know this problem very well.